# iTextSharp Header Footer help

Tags: header, itext, footer

I am using iTextSharp to generate pdf in my .net application.
Now I want to add Header and Footer in my pdf document.
I got code from a site something like given below but it doesn't work.
[
 //we Add a Header that will show up on PAGE 1
 HeaderFooter header = new HeaderFooter(new Phrase("This is a header"), false);
 document.Header = header;
]
I create document object like:-
Dim document As text.Document = New text.Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 25, 25)
But it doesn't have property of Header as mention in the above code.
Can anyone suggest me how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I cannot help you regarding your iTextSharp issue as we have stopped using it when we found out, that it cannot automatically break the content for multi-page PDFs, and it forces the programmer to hardcode critical values leading to bad coding.

In the same time, if it's not a problem to change the PDF generator library for your project then you may check out **[PDFSharp and Migradoc](http://www.pdfsharp.net/)** which we're using succesfully for over 1 year now. Much simpler to integrate then iTextSharp, requires less code, it has great charting tools, a much more intuitive object oriented model and the best part is that it has a **great documentation with a dozen of working example projects**.

Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks dude,Its really helpful for generating PDf doc. in .NET.